# Taking the average of two years, written as [1858-60]

Tags: python

There are a few cases where the date is written as 'created ca. 1858-60', where a human reader would understand it as 'created ca 1858-1860.'

As such, imagine two integers representing years.

```
a = 1858
b = 60
```

I want to be able to get `a+b == 1859`.

I could parse them to strings, take the first two characters (`'18'`), concatinate the shorter string and parse them back to numbers, sure, but..that seems a bit round-a-bound.

What would be the Pythonic way to deal with this?

Comment: `60` seems too ambiguous to me, is it always the case that `b` shares the century prefix of `a`?

Comment: What are the "specifications"? Is it also meant to work for a three digit year?

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes, b always shares the prefix of a.

Comment: @Goodra Not required.

Comment: I just want to clarify -- you will NEVER have to deal with `1999-01`?

Comment: @AdamSmith. No, never.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you're going about this wrong. The easier approach is to add the century to `b`, then use them as normal numbers now that they're equatable.

```
def add_century(n: int, from_century=1900) -> int:
    """add_century turns a two-digit year into a four-digit year.

    takes a two-digit year `n` and a four-digit year `from_century` and
    adds the leading two digits from the latter to the former.
    """

    century = from_century // 100 * 100
    return century + n
```

Then you can do:

```
a, b = 1858, 60
b = add_century(b, from_century=a)
result = (a + b) / 2
```

---

Treating the numbers this way provides two benefits.

First of all, you clarify the edge case you might have. ***Explicitly*** adding the century from one onto the ending years from the other makes it very clear what's happened if the code should return the wrong result.

Secondly, transforming objects into equatable terms isn't just a good idea, it's required in languages that are, shall we say, less *accepting* than Python is. A quick transformation so two items are equatable is an easy way to make sure you're not confusing things down the road.

Comment: This answer doesn't work across century boundaries and the result is a float (in python 3).

Comment: @AlexTaylor OP explicitly said his code will never cross the century boundary, and I consider a floating-point result correct here while OP doesn't specify.

Comment: Integers work in floating point up to way past reasonable years, so floating point is perfectly fine. Also this conveniently works for things like 1964-6.

Comment: @corsiKa it doesn't work for that, actually. `add_century(6, 1964) = 1906`

Comment: I think this is the right approach, convert the input immediately, making it explicit what assumptions you're making. But I would make the version that parses 1999-01 correctly even if it's massively unlikely, just to avoid any possible misunderstanding in future. I don't think anyone will write 1999-01 to mean "between 1999 and 1901".

Comment: I'm not sure why you called the result "difference". It's an average, not a difference, unless I'm mistaken. (I'd edit the answer but I'm not sure enough that this was just a simple mistake... did you mean something specific with that name?)

Comment: @PeterHansen I'm not sure I like "average" any better, but you're right that "difference" doesn't make much sense there. I corrected to `result`.

Comment: Yeah, I used "average" merely because it's in the question, but it now seems to me that "midpoint" might be a better term. Result works fine too though.

Answer (score 13):

This version works entirely with integers and handles cross-century boundaries:

```
def year_range_average(a, b):
    return a + (b - (a % 100) + 100) % 100 // 2

>>> year_range_average(1858, 60)
1859
>>> year_range_average(1858, 61)
1859
>>> year_range_average(1858, 62)
1860
>>> year_range_average(1898, 2)
1900
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string with a regex such as `(dd)` to get groups XXYY-ZZ those will be stored as g1 g2 and g3.

```
result = int(g1) * 1000 + (int(g2) + int(g3))/2
```

This of course assumes the prefix is always the same. So 1890-10 would break...

It also assumes the prefix is always there.

Overall doing the string concat and average seems better...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
a = 1858
b = 60

def average_year(a,b):
    c = int(str(a)[:2]) * 100
    a1 = int(str(a)[2:])
    return c + (b + a1)/2

print average_year(a,b)
> 1859
```

Answer (score 0):

Mm if you don't want to convert to strings... Let's do some maths :

```
a = 1858
b = 60
cent = 0
s = 0
if a < 2000:
    s = a - 1000
    c, y = divmod(s, 100)
    cent = 1000
else:
     s = a - 2000
     cent = 2000
     c, y = divmod(s, 100)
avg = (b + y) / 2
result = cent + (c*100) + avg
```